# Path to directory after click once publish

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, web-deployment

I have a win forms application. And I have a folder, which I've included to assembly with another tool. In my code I need to get path to this folder. This is line in my config is working fine:

```
<add key="xulrunnerPath" value="../../../xulrunner" />
```

But after publish and install I've got an error. I know that this folder will be in the same directory after install. Question: how should I set path in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the location of the currently executing EXE using this:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Then you can construct a relative path from here. Everything that's copied during a ClickOnce installation is copied to that folder or a subfolder of this folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your folder to your project from publish->application files->your folder name and before doing this right click your folder and make build action Content

Comment: they are in the application file. I just need to get path to folder with this file.

Comment: I think if you did what i said only folder name will be enough for path

Comment: Files are in the application files. Name is not enough.

Comment: I solved similar issue by doing this it worked for me i m sorry

Answer (score 0):

you can get the path like this:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
String path = Path.Combine (info.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName, "xulrunner");
```

Comment: Current directory and install directory are not necessarily the same at run-time.